# How to set text to the same high as picture?

Tags: html, css

[Image who it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7Bmh.png)

I want to have text in the same high as picture in one card. Please, how can I do it?

I tried some combinations with margin and padding, but nothing work.

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 30%;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: #444;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.card ul li img{
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.picture{
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 400px;
  max-width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.text{
  display: inline-block;
}

.text h1{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
<div class="card">
 <div class="picture">
   <img src="pictures/picture2.jpg" alt="pic1">
 </div>
 <div class="text">
   <h1>Lorem ipsum <br>dolor sitam</h1>
   <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br> amet, consectetur</h3>
   <p>0,99€ /ks </p>
   <button class="button">Zobraziť viac</button>
 </div>
```

I expect to have text which top line start in top, not in the middle.

Comment: `vertical-align:top;` on the `.text` class

Answer (score 1):

Add a `vertical-align:top` css rule to your `.text` class. This will bring the div to the top of it's container and align it with the image.

[image]

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 30%;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: #444;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.card ul li img{
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.picture{
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 400px;
  max-width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.text{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.text h1{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="picture">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x400" alt="pic1">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum <br>dolor sitam</h1>
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br> amet, consectetur</h3>
      <p>0,99€ /ks </p>
      <button class="button">Zobraziť viac</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `vertical-align: top;`to the `.class`

**CSS**

```
.text{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/sj801n7u/)**